# Can a class property be initialized to an array of closures?

Tags: php, arrays, closures, class-properties

I am trying to store some validation functions inside a static configuration array.  Storing functions in array seems to work, however, when I put the same code inside a class, it fails.  Anyone know what's going on?

```
$functions = array(
     'function1' => function($echo) {
           echo $echo;
      }
);

$functions['function1']("hello world");
// Works

//----------

class A {
    public static $functions = array(
        'function1' => function($echo) {
             echo $echo;
         }
    );
}

A::$functions['function1']("hello world");
//Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)
```

Comment: Same error when running the code on either Windows or Linux.

PHP version 5.6.30 on Windows
PHP version 5.5.9 on Linux

Comment: That's not allowed in PHP. You can only assign basic values to class variables in the initial definition. You can set the closure to it from within a function though, e.g. in a `A::prepare()` method, set `self::$functions['function1'] = function($echo) { echo $echo; };`.

Comment: Class variables must be initialized to CONSTANT expressions, at least in 5.x.

Answer (score 2):

When I run this using PHP 7 (PHP 5 will also error out), I am getting an error that basically says expressions when instantiating class variables is not allowed.  This is how this will work instead:

```
$functions = array(
    'function1' => function($echo) {
        echo $echo;
    }
);

$functions['function1']("hello world");
// Works

//----------

class A {
    public static $functions = [];
}

A::$functions['function1'] = function($echo) {
    echo $echo;
};

A::$functions['function1']("hello world");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may
>   include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: As PHP's OO support is class-based, you should instantiate A::$functions inside a constructor, not after the class definition.